# Docker COPY all files and folders except some files/folders

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile copy command allows golang regex. But with the regex, I am not able to omit a particular folder.

For example, if the directory has:-

```
public
dist
webapp
somefile.txt
anotherfile.txt
```

Now, how should I write the expression for COPY such that it omits '`webapp`' and copy all other files and folders?

**NOTE**: I know I can put it to .dockerignore, but in later build stage in the same Dockerfile, I want to copy that folder - '`webapp`'

Answer (score 5):

You have two choices:

1. List all directories you want to copy directly:

   COPY ["foldera", "folderc", "folderd", ..., "/dstPath]
2. Try to exclude some paths but also make sure that all paths patterns are not including the path we want to exclude:

   COPY ["folder[^b]*", "file*", "/dstPath"]

Also you can read more about available solutions in this issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15771

Answer (score 1):

### COPY with exclusions work around

I have a PHP + Node app, with *both* `node_modules` and `vendor` directories, with layer caching in place.

I was looking to exclude my dependencies, by excluding some files from being copied, but since Docker `COPY` does not support exclusions, I took a different approach, to get my dependencies cached in a different layer.

It took a combination of 3 different steps:

#### Step 1

Script the tarring the `node_modules` and `vendor` directories in my build process:

```
tar -cf ./node_modules.tgz --directory=./src/node_modules .
tar -cf ./vendor.tgz --directory=./src/vendor . 
docker build ...
rm node_modules.tgz vendor.tgz
docker push ...
```

#### Step 2

Use `.dockerignore` to ignore the `node_modules` and `vendor` directories:

```
src/node_modules
src/vendor
```

#### Step 3

Add the tar files to the project, before copying the rest of my source code:

```
ADD node_modules.tgz /var/www/node_modules
ADD vendor.tgz /var/www/vendor
COPY ./src /var/www
```

Obviously, the first build is slow while the layer gets cached, and whenever the cache is invalidated (e.g. new packages).

Credit to `jason-kane` from here for inspiration: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15771#issuecomment-207113714

Something else to note: my `vendor` and `node_modules` directories are in the same folder as the source code.